# Invalid conversion from HANDLE to HINSTANCE (Getting a kernel function's address)

Tags: c++, windows, kernel32, getprocaddress

I'm trying to find the address of the `SetProcessDEPPolicy` function of the Windows API in `kernel32` ([see my problem here and the first answer I got](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80107/getting-a-dep-exception-when-trying-to-call-setprocessdepexceptionfalse?noredirect=1#comment131272_80107)).

I've never written a Windows C++ program before so I'm a bit lost but I have this so far:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HANDLE kernel32 = GetModuleHandle("kernel32");
    FARPROC* funcAddr = (FARPROC *) GetProcAddress(kernel32, "SetProcessDEPPolicy");
    std::cout << "@ ";
}
```

I'm getting the following error on line 7:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\John\Desktop>c++ finddep.cpp -o finddep.exe finddep.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)': finddep.cpp:7:79: error: invalid conversion from 'HANDLE {aka void*}' to 'HINSTA NCE' [-fpermissive]   FARPROC funcAddr = (FARPROC *) GetProcAddress(kernel32, "SetProcessDEPPolicy") ;
                                                                               ^
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:50:0,
from finddep.cpp:1: c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1675:27: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'int (__ attribute__((__stdcall__)) * GetProcAddress(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))()' [-fpermissive ]  WINBASEAPI FARPROC WINAPI GetProcAddress(HINSTANCE,LPCSTR);
^ finddep.cpp:7:79: error: cannot convert 'int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) **)() ' to 'FARPROC {aka int (__attribute__((__stdcall__)) *)()}' in initialization   FARPROC funcAddr = (FARPROC *) GetProcAddress(kernel32, "SetProcessDEPPolicy") ;
```

I couldn't find any good ideas on how to solve this from Google.

(Once I get this to compile, how can I print the address in the pointer?)

EDIT: Added Cyclone's suggestion from the comment, getting same error `Invalid conversion from HANDLE to HINSTANCE`

Comment: `FARPROC* funcAddr = (FARPROC *) `

Comment: @Cyclone Thanks for pointing that out, but get exactly same error by declaring it as pointer. `Invalid conversaion from HANDLE to HINSTANCE`

Comment: The error is caused by passing an invalid parameter to `GetProcAddress()`, I believe. Just to make sure, call that function in one step and then convert it to a `FARPROC*` in a second one. See the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, the function returns a `HMODULE`, not a `HANDLE`.

Comment: Also check out the return type of `GetProcAddress()` and stop listening to @Cyclone as long as they suggest blindly casting in order to silence the compiler. For use with `GetProcAddress()`, you will need a cast, but you should be able to use `reinterpret_cast`, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you should do it:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HMODULE kernel32 = GetModuleHandleA("kernel32");
    FARPROC *funcAddr = (FARPROC *)GetProcAddress(kernel32, "SetProcessDEPPolicy");
    std::cout << "@" << funcAddr;
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks, will give you the point when I can.